# SOAP in php doesn't return values from MySql

Tags: c#, php, mysql, soap

I am currently working on a  WebService which is developed in PHP and MySQL.
My application which is developed in C# and WPF is consuming those services.

My SOAP server is using `PDO` to access the database records.
**Problem**
When I try to access the webservice from my application I get no results from the database.
Here is an example of my `C#` application trying to retrieve some info:

```
bool result;
try
{
    PADR_API.PADR_APIWSClient client = new PADR_API.PADR_APIWSClient();
    string friends = client.GetFirendsList(8);        
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string i = ex.Message;//excuse this attempt but I am desperate to find the cause
    throw;
}
return result;
```

However what I get in the response is only my test message.
Here is the `PHP` code from my SOAP server:

```
public function GetFirendsList($id){
    $response = new getFreindsListResponse();
    $response->return = 'test of a message with following ';
    $response->return .= 'friends: ';
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****', $user, $pwd);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id,friends FROM PADR_users WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
//        foreach ($stmt as $row) {
//            $response->return .= $row['friends'];
//        }
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $response->return .= $row['friends'];
    }
    //$response->return = var_dump($stmt);
    //$response->return = $pdo->errorInfo()[0];
    //$response->return = $res;
    return $response;
}
```

And here is the code of how I set up my SOAP server:

```
$options=array('cache_wsdl'=> WSDL_CACHE_NONE);
//create a new SOAP server
$server = new SoapServer('PADRAPIWS.wsdl', $options);//,$options
//attach the API class to the SOAP Server
$server->setClass('PADR_APIWS');
//start the SOAP requests handler
$server->handle();
```

I have also tried using a `PHP` `SOAPClient`

```
$options = array(//'location' => 'http://localhost/index.php', 
            'uri' => 'http://localhost/',
            'trace' => 1, 
            'exceptions' => true, 
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 
            'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);
$client = new SoapClient('http://padr.orgfree.com/index.php?wsdl', $options);
$client->__setLocation('http://padr.orgfree.com/index.php');
//var_dump($client);
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
var_dump($client->__getTypes());
$res = $client->GetFirendsList(array('Id'=> 8));
var_dump($res);
```

What is really interesting is that when I use my code in the php file without SOAP then the query returns result fine. As soon as I want to do it through the SOAP I only get back `test of a message with following friends:`.
I have very little experience with `PHP` and to be honest I don't know where the fault is? I have been following few tutorials about [creating the SOAP with WSDL](http://osarogabriel.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/how-to-generate-wsdl-for-php-soap-server.html) and [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).
However last one didn't provide any insight on the issue and to be honest I don't know how to describe the issue because I don't know where it lies.
P.S. here is the result from the client:

> array(5) { [0]=> string(65) "GetFirendsListResponse GetFirendsList(GetFirendsList $parameters)" [1]=> string(68) "UpdateIPAddressResponse UpdateIPAddress(UpdateIPAddress $parameters)" [2]=> string(74) "CheckIfRegisteredResponse CheckIfRegistered(CheckIfRegistered $parameters)" [3]=> string(47) "RegisterResponse Register(Register $parameters)" [4]=> string(50) "AddFriendResponse AddFriend(AddFriend $parameters)" } array(10) { [0]=> string(53) "struct AddFriend { string nickname; int friendId; }" [1]=> string(45) "struct AddFriendResponse { boolean return; }" [2]=> string(34) "struct GetFirendsList { int Id; }" [3]=> string(49) "struct GetFirendsListResponse { string return; }" [4]=> string(46) "struct CheckIfRegistered { string nickname; }" [5]=> string(53) "struct CheckIfRegisteredResponse { boolean return; }" [6]=> string(63) "struct UpdateIPAddress { string nickname; string ipaddress; }" [7]=> string(51) "struct UpdateIPAddressResponse { boolean return; }" [8]=> string(56) "struct Register { string nickname; string ipaddress; }" [9]=> string(44) "struct RegisterResponse { boolean return; }" } object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["return"]=> string(42) "test of a message with following friends: " }

Comment: I don't know what you did with the yellow block, but the text only shows when you use mouse over :)

Comment: That's right, I tried to keep the question clean without too much information. If you want to do use it in your question just use `>! ` before your text.

Comment: How did you test your php code (ie: Where you say that that part works)?

Comment: Through by browser with this URL http://padr.orgfree.com/SoapClient.php

Comment: Ok, the difference I see is this: `$client->GetFirendsList(array('Id'=> 8));`, while your C# code just seems to pass an integer. Can you add a check in your `Firends` function for this to see if the C# interface finally gives you the array too?

Comment: The WSDL declares that function return (BTW I am aware of the misspelling mistake) as a string so what I am returning is a string. BTW I tried using `$res = $client->GetFirendsList(8);` but no avail.

Comment: Test your php client then with 8 instead of `array(...)` just to see if it also fails. I think the parameter might just be parsed incorrect, so then you only have to change 1 line: Place id in array.

Comment: I can't use the array as my `C#` client expects `int` as a parameter.

Comment: My idea is to catch that on the php side: Check if array in php, if not array then place value in array and execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer to the problem was that SOAP WS is using SOAP Envelope for transferring messages from client to the server.
So what has worked was
`$request = array('Id' => array('Value'=> 21));
$res = $client->GetFirendsList($request);`
where wsdl method looks like this:

```
<message name="GetFirendsList">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:GetFirendsList"/>
</message>
<message name="GetFirendsListResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:GetFirendsListResponse"/>
</message>
<operation name="GetFirendsList">
  <input wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/PADR_APIWS/GetFirendsListRequest" message="tns:GetFirendsList"/>
  <output wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/PADR_APIWS/GetFirendsListResponse" message="tns:GetFirendsListResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="GetFirendsList">
  <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
  <input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </input>
  <output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </output>
</operation>
```

And the xsd file:

```
<xs:complexType name="getFirendsList">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

Sorry for the extensive xml.
and here is the `C#` code:

```
PADR_API.getFirendsList request = new PADR_API.getFirendsList();
request.Value = 8;
client.GetFirendsList(request);
```

All this now works.
**Conclusion**
So lesson learned from this is that even if you want to send just an `int` or any other primitive type you need to envelope it in an object that is then treated as a SOAP envelope.
The SOAP server requires a response type which has to be defined on the server side like so:

```
class getGetFirendsListResponse {
    public $return;
}
```